# How to store index of a for loop in an array Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, string

I have a for loop running on string length. the first loop looks for a character common in the second loop. I want to save the index of nameString that is common in an array or a string. Please help. Code is mentioned below.

```
for (int i=0; i < nameString.length; i++) {

        char currentLetter = [nameString characterAtIndex:i];

    for (int j=0; j < partnersNameString.length; j++) {
        if (currentLetter == [partnersNameString characterAtIndex:j]) {

            NSRange range;
            range.length=1;
            range.location=j;
           [partnersNameString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
            calculateField.text = partnersNameString;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about doing what you are looking for: you can use a "plain" C array with a count, or you can use an `NSMutableArray` with wrappers.

The first way would look like this:

```
NSUInteger indexes[MAX_LENGTH];
NSUInteger lastIndex = 0;
for (int i=0; i < nameString.length; i++) {
    char currentLetter = [nameString characterAtIndex:i];
    for (int j=0; j < partnersNameString.length; j++) {
        if (currentLetter == [partnersNameString characterAtIndex:j]) {
            indexes[lastIndex++] = i;
            // Go through the rest of your code
            ...
        }
    }
}
for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i != lastIndex ; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Found match at index %u", indexes[i]);
}
```

The second way looks similar, except now you need to use [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to wrap the data going into [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSMutableArray *indexes = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i < nameString.length; i++) {
    char currentLetter = [nameString characterAtIndex:i];
    for (int j=0; j < partnersNameString.length; j++) {
        if (currentLetter == [partnersNameString characterAtIndex:j]) {
            [indexes addObject[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
            // Go through the rest of your code
            ...
        }
    }
}
for (NSNumber in indexes) {
   NSLog(@"Found match at index %i", [[indexes objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSMutablearray for that

```
NSMutableArray myArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i < nameString.length; i++) {

        char currentLetter = [nameString characterAtIndex:i];

    for (int j=0; j < partnersNameString.length; j++) {
        if (currentLetter == [partnersNameString characterAtIndex:j]) {
            //And add it here
            [myArray addObject:currentLetter];
            NSRange range;
            range.length=1;
            range.location=j;
           [partnersNameString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
            calculateField.text = partnersNameString;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to put currentLetter in array. I want to save index of nameString (value of i) in array for which corresponding letter in partner string is equal

Answer (score 1):

```
[myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```